# CakePHP - Session Timeout - Idle User

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, session-timeout

I am using Cakephp 1.3 and having a lot of troubles with session timeouts.

So, here's my core.php file.

```
 Configure::write('Session.save', 'cake');
 Configure::write('Session.cookie', 'TESTING');
 Configure::write('Session.timeout', '0.01');
 Configure::write('Session.start', true);
 Configure::write('Session.checkAgent', false);
 Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
```

Here comes the first problem, on session.timwout it is specified as SECONDS but if I put 1 using low that gives my cookie expire of 5 hours (?). with this setting I am getting 3 minutes to cookie expire, I don't understand that, it should be 1 x 300 seconds = 5 minutes. what kind of math is that?

And the main problem is that this is not being respected, when I log to my website I can see it generated a session and will expire in 3 minutes, but as soon as I log on and click a link i get back to the log in page, which means I get de authenticated in less than 30 seconds.

I am trying to set such a low value for testing, I know high and medium security values regenerate session between requests but I would like to understand what's going on.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Session lifetime and cookie lifetime aren't equal. [Session lifetime](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/cake_session.php#L199) is calculated by

```
Security::inactiveMins() * Configure::read('Session.timeout')
```

where as [cookie lifetime](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/cake_session.php#L481) is calculated by

```
Configure::read('Session.timeout') * (Security::inactiveMins() * 60)
```

So on a security level of `low`, a session timeout of `1` results in a session lifetime of `300` seconds, and a cookie lifetime of `18000` seconds, ie `5` hours.

And when using a `0.01` second timeout, session lifetime would be `3` seconds, and cookie lifetime would be `180` seconds, and therefore you are being logged out so fast.

As you've experienced for yourself, there's no need to worry about the longer cookie lifetime (which I guess is to prevent the cookie becoming invalid before the session times out, but I could be wrong on that), once the session times out, the cookie is [being invalidated](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/cake_session.php#L642) and finally [overwritten](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3/cake/libs/cake_session.php#L644).

Comment: hey @ndm, thanks for your reply, I need to do some testing and I would like to set session lefetime to 5 minutes, in order to get that value I set session.timeout to 1 and security level to low. 1 * 300 = 300 seconds or 5 mins! but I when I check the cookie it's set for 5 hours, and if I send some post after those 5 minutes of my session it still works, I guess I should have been logged out, am I right?

Comment: Sorry, of course I ment `5` hours (I've edited my answer). The cookie lifetime of `5` hours is correct, and yes, you should get logged out after the `5` minute session timeout, regardless of the longer cookie lifetime. I've just tried it with your values and it works fine, the session is beeing invalidated after `5` minutes of inactivity and I'm being logged out. Is your app maybe sending automated AJAX requests that would cause the timeout to be renewed?

Comment: Oh yes! there is an AJAX on page specifically to avoid timeouts! thanks a ton @ndm, I'll remove that and do my tests! =)